# Laravel Auth User via External System

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-authorization

I am new to the Laravel framework and loving it so far! The part that is giving me the biggest headache to the point of giving up is trying to implement a login system that I have already coded and want to refactor into the Laravel framework. I have read ALOT of posts and I think the framework and how everything is connected is effing with me.

GOAL (Typical OAuth2 Client flow):

1. User is directed to external login system (custom no third-party
   available)
2. User comes back with authorization code App calls API
   with auth code to get access_token and id_token
3. Using the id_token...store this information (in database or not and just keep reading from the id_token stored somewhere)
4. User now has access to pages requiring an authenication

All the words are just getting confused in my head and I don't even know where to start (Guards, Middleware, UserProviders, Contracts....)

Thank you and let me know if you need more information (especially to prove that's I've given this a run and/or ALOT of thought).

Explaining to my like I'm 5, at this point, would be preferred :P

Comment: have you read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport ?

Comment: @Shubhampokhriyal Yes, I am looking for my app to be an OAuth Client not an OAuth Server.